# Stored procedures using variable as table name and retrieve data in output variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure in which I am uaing variable as table name and also retrieve the result of the query in output parameter

Following is the stored procedure`

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE  PROCEDURE db_test.test(IN tblname varchar(100),OUT Valv varchar(100))
BEGIN
SET @a = CONCAT('SELECT name INTO  Valv FROM ', tbname ,' limit 1') ;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @a;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

When I call the above procedure using below command

```
CALL db_test.test('db_test.t_names',@name);
select @name;
```

I am getting error as 
PROCEDURE db_test.test can't return a result set in the given context

I have searched solution for this error but could not find it.
Please suggest solution for above query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use user variables in prepared statements. A [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15263) exists already.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE  PROCEDURE db_test.test(IN tblname varchar(100),OUT Valv varchar(100))
BEGIN
SET @a = CONCAT('SELECT name INTO @Valv FROM ', tbname ,' limit 1') ;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @a;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
SET Valv = @Valv;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE  PROCEDURE db_test.test(IN tblname varchar(100),OUT Valv varchar(100))
BEGIN
SET @a = CONCAT('SELECT name INTO  ', Valv ,' FROM ', tbname ,' limit 1') ;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @a;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: tbname is not the name of a parameter.